# git: how can I delete this file for good?

Tags: git

I have a file that keeps coming back in my local git repository, which I'm trying to get rid of, once and for all.

Note that this file was never in my .gitignore

The situation is this:

I do:

```
git status

On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        src/com/mygfx/gui/face/MuscleSliderX.java

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

then I do:

```
git rm ./src/com/mygfx/gui/face/MuscleSliderX.java 

git add -A

git commit -m "Delete MuscleSliderX.java"

git push origin master

git status

On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

the next time (another day) I start the day with a

```
git status

On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        src/com/mygfx/gui/face/MuscleSliderX.java

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

How can I delete this file and make git forget about it henceforward.

Comment: It is an untracked file, you don't need to `rm`, `add` or `commit` it's removal because *it is already untracked*. Simply deleting the file will suffice. If the file keeps reappearing, then something else is putting it there.

Comment: you seem to have done all the right things, something else (possibly your IDE if you are using one) is creating the file automatically

Comment: @CoryKramer I did remove if via `rm ./src/com/mygfx/gui/face/MuscleSliderX.java` and so it was gone for the rest of that day, but now (new day) it has risen from the dead once again.

Comment: I'd grep all the files in your repo for the file name of that file. Maybe that way you could see if there is some script in your repo which generates that file....

Comment: I've grepped that file, and found instances of the name in .git folder (inside commit messages). And found instances in my IDE's project definition folder (.idea/.workspace.xml).
And it keeps reappearing after a system reboot (seems connected to system reboot, somehow). So yeah must be a problem outside of git, I guess..

Comment: weird, it seems that IntelliJ keeps a local history of the file, for itself, perhaps IntelliJ is the culpable: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2008/01/using-local-history-to-restore-deleted-files/

Answer (score 1):

`untracked` means git doesn't know anything about it, but something has placed it in your work tree.  That means a few things:

First, it means your `git commit -m "Delete MuscleSliderX.java"` *should* be erroring out ("nothing to commit").  I'm assuming a reasonably modern git version; I don't know if it always showed this error; but regardless, if the `status` output you've reported is accurate, then the only command that's doing anything is the `git rm` - and actually just a plain `rm` would suffice since the file isn't staged anyway.

Second, it means something *outside* of git keeps recreating that file.  I have no idea what, but fiddling with git won't fix it.  You don't need git to forget the file once and for all - it forgets everything about the file, and consequently when the file is placed there by something/someone else, it doesn't know not to tell you it's there.

If you *do* want it not to tell you about the file even when something else puts it in your work tree, then you need to put an entry in `.gitignore`.  But that still won't prevent the file from being placed in your work tree.  If you want the file to stop appearing, you need to figure out what's creating it.

Answer (score 0):

Try use git clean -f to get over untracked files

Comment: That will behave no differently than `rm`ing the file